# how to scan barcode and save to google drive?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, barcode, barcode-scanner

i want to make a stock opname for our warehouse by scanning barcode of each items using scanner and save the result in google spreadsheet.

i have to scan 4 barcode (Item Number, Number1, Number2, IDBARCODE) for each items like the data bellow automatically without click my keyboard (after scan 4 barcode then go to row bellow):

```
Item Number     Number1   Number2   IDBARCODE
KMJ15011988     AB12345   CD78901   IDBARCODE1234
NKH24061988     AB12346   CD78902   IDBARCODE1235
OTY27121988     AB12347   CD78903   IDBARCODE1236
JWY30041989     AB12348   CD78904   IDBARCODE1237
LJH25011990     AB12349   CD78905   IDBARCODE1238
HCS11021990     AB12350   CD78906   IDBARCODE1239
```

I have tried to scan all the barcode and the result always be like this :

```
Item Number     Number1   Number2   IDBARCODE
KMJ15011988    
AB12345
CD78901
IDBARCODE1234
NKH24061988
AB12346
CD78902
IDBARCODE1235
OTY27121988
AB12347
CD78903
IDBARCODE1236
JWY30041989
AB12348
CD78904
IDBARCODE1237
LJH25011990
AB12349
CD78905
IDBARCODE1238
HCS11021990
AB12350
CD78906
IDBARCODE1239
```

May you know how to fix it? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: from my knowledge, if you use microsoft excel, it is possible without using keyboard. But if you use google spreadsheet, it just has too few options and it's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could continue to scan as you are doing and then convert the single column of data to the format you want. Assuming you scan data is in the first sheet, add a second sheet and run this. It will format the data in four columns.

```
function SPLIT() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sh0 = ss.getSheets()[0], sh1 = ss.getSheets()[1];

  // get data from sheet 1
  var data = sh0.getDataRange().getValues();

  // create array to hold data
  var aMain = new Array();

  // itterate through data and add to array
  for(var i=1, dLen=data.length-1; i<dLen; i=i) {
      aMain.push([data[i][0],data[i+1][0],data[i+2][0],data[i+3][0]]);
    i=i+4
    }
  // add array of data to second sheet
  sh1.getRange(2, 1, aMain.length, 4).setValues(aMain);
}
```

Add your column headers to the second sheet.